# Replace all the ocurrance of a string in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to replace a particular string in (the text of) all the descendant elements of a given element.

`innerHTML` cannot be used as this sequence can appear in attributes. I have tried using XPath, but it seems the interface is essentially read-only. Because this is limited to one element, functions like `document.getElementsByTagName` cannot be used either.

Could any suggest any way to do this? Any jQuery or pure DOM method is acceptable.

Edit:

Some of the answers are suggesting the problem I was trying to work around: modifying the text directly on an Element will cause all non-Text child nodes to be removed.

So the problem essentially comes down to how to efficiently select all the Text nodes in a tree. In XPath, you can easily do it as `//text()`, but the current XPath interface does not allow you to change these Text nodes it seems.

One way to do this is by recursion as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526610/499922) by Bergi. Another [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526042/499922) is to use the `find('*')` selector of jQuery, but this is a bit more expensive. Still waiting to see if there' are better solutions.

Comment: [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) let you traverse and modify the dom, access the descendants and the siblings of an element. And much more.

Comment: @ADC, unfortunately there's nothing like XPath's text() selector....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a simple selfmade DOM-iterator, which walks recursively over all nodes:

```
(function iterate_node(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) { // Node.TEXT_NODE
        var text = node.data.replace(/any regular expression/g, "any replacement");
        if (text != node.data) // there's a Safari bug
            node.data = text;
    } else if (node.nodeType === 1) { // Node.ELEMENT_NODE
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            iterate_node(node.childNodes[i]); // run recursive on DOM
        }
    }
})(content); // any dom node
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be to surf through *all* available nodes (TextNodes included) and apply a regexp pattern on the results. To grab TextNodes as well, you need to invoke jQuerys `.contents()`. For instance:

```
var search = "foo",
    replaceWith = 'bar',
    pattern = new RegExp( search, 'g' );


function searchReplace( root ) {
    $( root ).contents().each(function _repl( _, node ) {
        if( node.nodeType === 3 )
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace( pattern, replaceWith );
        else searchReplace( node );
    });
}

$('#apply').on('click', function() {
    searchReplace( document.getElementById('rootNode') );
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h8Rxu/3/

Reference: [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: I think the assignment to textContent will remove all non-Text nodes similarly to the call to jQuery's `text()` as suggested by jbabey.

Comment: @billc.cn: right, I updated the code and the example, recursion should do the job there.

Comment: That code is overly complicated and mixed jQuery with native DOM methods. Why, for example, do you apply String.trim on the nodeValues before replace()?

Comment: I optimized that example a little. Mixing in jQuery just because OP allowed for it, so it auto-fixes TextNodes bugs and it saves some typing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just got it myself:

```
$('#id').find('*').each(function(){
    $.each(this.childNodes, function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 3) {
            this.data = this.data.toUpperCase();
        }
    })
})
```

I used toUpperCase() here to make the result more obvious, but any String operation would be valid there.

Comment: I guess `Text` object doesn't exist in IE8 and lower. Better use `this.nodeType === 3`.

Comment: This will *break* where `Text` is not a reference to an object, such as in MSHTML < 8 (IE < 8). Same for the `data` property. It will also break where `instanceof` is not supported, although those implementations are rare nowadays, and jQuery is not likely to support them in the first place. You should add feature tests and follow duri's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#parent').children().each(function () {
    var that = $(this);

    that.text(that.text().replace('test', 'foo'));
});
```

If you prefer to search through all children instead of just immediate children, use `.find()` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExwDx/

Edit: Documentation for [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/), and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: This is what I was working on before I posted this question. The problem is, if the element has any non-Text children, they will be removed as a result of the call to `text()`. Obviously this is not acceptable.

Comment: it will include text nodes, and it will not remove non-text children.

Comment: @jbabey: you're right, removed my comment. Do you know since what version `.children()` also returns TextNodes ?

Comment: pretty confusing tho, the doc still says "* .children() does not return text nodes; to get all children including text and comment nodes, use .contents().*"

Comment: `children()` does not return any text nodes, but text() will include all the text in the element (including its children's), as the DOM property `.textContent` does. However, setting text using `text()` WILL remove all children as there's no logical way to tell which part of the string belongs to which child.