# Remove special characters from string except special character inside HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one string with HTML tags and special characters (\,:). I have remove special characters from the string using `.replace(/[\:]/g,'')` but the problem is my string contains HTML tags which have style property so the RegEx which I used is removing `:` from style property of span tags.

I do not want to remove `:` from style property of span tags

Anyone suggest solution for this?

Find below link to regex101
https://regex101.com/r/UAOuDG/1

Comment: Don't do this. Manipulate the DOM with DOM APIs. There are dozens of posts here on SO about how to do search/replace on text in the DOM.

Comment: @torazaburo. You are right, I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526610/6188402) which, I think, could answer the OP question if he manage to change a bit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this but if you have to do it any way there's a workaround (not 100% guaranteed)

```js
var str = "By: <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Anita</span> <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Elberse</span> and : Sir Alex Ferguson";

console.log(str.replace(/<\w+(?=[ >])[^<>]*>|(:)/g, function(_o, O_) {
    return  O_ ? '' : _o;
}));
```

**Regex explanation**:

```
<\w+(?=[ >]) # Begin matching opening tags
[^<>]*>      # Up to end
|            # Or (then)
(:)          # Any remaining colons
```

Comment: Why complicate things? [`.replace(/(<.*?>)|:/g, (m, $1) => $1 || '')`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8kne4g72/)

Comment: Well, that's not right. You're producing much more drawbacks.

Comment: Can you please explain _drawbacks_

Comment: Yes, like you may not want to skip colons in *< My name is: <span>Jack</span> >*.

Comment: There's no reason for this downvote as this solution contains necessary warnings.

Comment: LOL No one noticed :D

Comment: An easy way to solve a problem! @ClasG

Answer (score 1):

## DOM; The right way

I wasn't going to add a DOM workaround since I respect tags under each topic. This answer exists against downvoters whom if don't comment their reason wouldn't make their days:

```js
// Build our XPath query
var textNodes = document.evaluate("//body/text()", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
// Hold a pointer to current node
var currentText = textNodes.iterateNext(); 
list = [];
// Iterate over all nodes and store them
while (currentText) {
  list.push(currentText);
  currentText = textNodes.iterateNext();
}
// Modify all their contents
list.forEach(function(x) {
  x.textContent = x.textContent.replace(':', '')
});
```

```html
<body>
  By: <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Anita</span> <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Elberse</span> and : Sir Alex Ferguson
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```js
a = "By: <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Anita</span> <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Elberse</span> and Sir : Alex Ferguson"
b = a.replace(/(?!([^<]+>))+:/g, "")
console.log("original :", a);
console.log("replaced :", b);
```

Comment: This won't work for `By: <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Anita</span> <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Elberse</span> and : Sir Alex Ferguson` When colons are in last part

Comment: What about *Sir : -> Alex Ferguson*?

Comment: it removed colon in last too

Comment: No, [you are mistaken](https://regex101.com/r/cIBIsX/1).

Comment: i am looking based on html tag <> , because thats user question

Comment: An HTML tag has its own definition which you didn't consider.

Answer (score 0):

First note - this isn't a fool proof solution. It's easy to break if you want to, but it'll handle many normal cases. Now, replacing

```
((['"])(?:\\.|(?!\2).)*\2)|:|([^'":]*)
```

with

```
$1$3
```

will remove all `:` that aren't inside quotes.

It starts of by trying to match and capture a whole string. If that doesn't match, it tries to match a colon. If that doesn't match either, everything up to the next colon or quote is matched and captured.

Now, if it was a string, it's in capture group 1. If it wasn't a string, nor a colon, it's in group 3. (2 is used *internally* to match the colons.)

To keep everything we want we replace the match with group 1 & 3, which of one will have the captured match.

Note that the string matched can be either single or double quoted and also contain escaped quotes.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pt7inY/2).

```js
var str="By: <span style='background-color:#ffc8c4;'>Anita</span> <span style=\"background-color:#ffc8c4;\">Elberse</span> and Sir Alex Ferguson";

console.log(str.replace(/((['"])(?:\\.|(?!\2).)*\2)|:|([^'":]*)/g, '$1$3'));
```

Comment: What if being inside quotes but not inside tags?

Comment: @revo How do you mean?

Comment: I mean when your input string is for example in such format *"We are making 16:9 ratio TVs", <span style="color:white">Jack</span> said.*

Comment: @revo That wouldn't be removed. Not sure how OP wan't that handled. Can probably be *sort of* handled. But as we all know - parsing html with regex **will** break sooner or later.

Comment: According to title *...except special character **inside** HTML tags* it should be removed. All of us know it's not the right tool for the job but as long as you think there could be an answer using regular expressions (as you have thought that way already) you try to bid one that is more suitable.